# python list comprehension with and without sub loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
d = {3: 21, 30: 200, 300: 2000}
```

If I do this,

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if key == i:
            val = value
```

i get the value right. But, if i change it to list comprehension way, I get empty 'val'

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    val = [value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key == i]
```

May I know what I miss here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rebind `val` each iteration of `range()`, while your first loop does not do this. Your first nested loop only sets `val` when `key == i` is true, which only happens when `i == 3` is true. Thus `val` is set correctly when `i == 3`, and *left alone entirely* when `i == 4` the next loop, while your second attempt with the list comprehension clobbers the `val = [21]` result with `val = []`.

Extend `val` each loop:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    val.extend(value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key == i)
```

or better yet, run just one list comprehension:

```
val = [value for i in range(1, 5) for key, value in d.iteritems() if key == i]
```

Demo:

```
>>> [value for i in range(1, 5) for key, value in d.iteritems() if key == i]
[21]
```

If all you were looking for is the value for the last `i` that is key in your dictionary, reverse the range, use `next()` with a generator expression, and just test if the key is in the dictionary, rather than loop over all items in the dictionary:

```
val = next(d[i] for i in range(4, 0, -1) if i in d)
```

This'll only test `4` and `3` using a membership test (O(1) operations), then exit the loop altogether.

Comment: we get [21] as list right. What change is required in same line to get 21 as value? can that be in one liner in list comprehension style

Comment: @Raghavan: you want to get the *last* result then; append `[-1]` to my last list comprehension. But that's rather.. inefficient, why not just stick with your version?

Comment: Alright. Thought if one liner would make cood look better!. I'll follow original version. Thanks

Comment: Isn't the original version wildly inefficient too? It seems to defeat the purpose of using a dictionary (beside the fact it could run the tests backwards and terminate early).

Comment: @MartijnPieters What about the fact it seems to be turning dictionary lookup into a linear search? Why not just `if i in d`?

Comment: @pvg: ick. I need to get myself another pot of tea. Or better, a crate of redbull.

Comment: @MartijnPieters hah. I was staring it at it for a while wondering whether _I_ wasn't sufficiently caffeinated yet.